# awk + find hostname after strings

Tags: awk

please advice how to print  the hostname ( NODE100 ) from the tnsnames.ora file by awk or sed

I mean I want to get each hostname after

```
    "HOST =" or "HOST=" or "HOST        =" etc
```

thx

```
 EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
   (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NODE100 )(PORT = 1521))
      )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc)
     )
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 perl -n -e '/HOST *= *([^ )]+)/ && print "$1\n"' tnsnames.ora
```